# Python transpose dataframe hot-encoded

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with repeated key values due to feature occurrences. However, I need to hot-encode those features.
**Exemplification:**
Current DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
              'feature_1':['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z']})
```

| key | feature_1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| A | Z |
| B | X |
| B | Y |
| B | Z |
| C | X |
| C | Y |
| C | Z |

I want to transform it into this:

| key | x_dummy | y_dummy | z_dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have no clue how to pull this off. Can you please guide me?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.key,df.feature_1)
Out[139]: 
feature_1  X  Y  Z
key               
A          1  1  1
B          1  1  1
C          1  1  1
```

Comment: That made the deal! Thank you!